# get a new date value based on the value in a combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, datepicker

my first question on SO,
I'm trying get a new date value based on the value in a combobox, with the formula:
datepicker + value in combobox = new date.

If you are wondering, yes, I'm new to js/jquery:)

The datepicker is created and the date shows in the requested input filed, but how do I add the calculation that gives me the new date based on the combobox?

This is as fare as I get..:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
       changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true,
        showButtonPanel:true,
        showOn:"both",
        minDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 1), 
        maxDate: new Date(2015,12, 1),
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
   $('#hjemreise_d2').val(dateText);
   }
});
});
</script>
```

..and here is the dropdown that I want to use to calculate the new date:

```
<select name="antall_uker" required class="txt" id="antall_uker" style="width: 100px;"               type="text"> 
    <option value="1">antall uker</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option> 
  </select>
<select id="hotellnavn"></select>
<select id="romtype"></select>
  </select>
```

.. where the value is the number of weeks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
var hjemreise = new Date(dateText);
hjemreise.setDate(hjemreise.getDate()+(7*$("#antall_uker").val()));
$('#hjemreise_d2').val(hjemreise); // maybe needs some formatting
```